# sqlalchemy: how to incrementally update row values of type TEXT or VARCHAR?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a table named `series` and it has one column named `message`, where it records any string messages/flags/phrases as the program process a job. I want to update the `message` value incrementally instead of replacing the value. For example:

`q = session.query(Series).filter(...)`

if I do

`q.update({Series.message: new_msg})`

the original contents in `message` would be wiped out and replaced with `new_msg`

I tried to do:

`q.update({Series.message: Series.message+'\n{}'.format(new_msg)})`

However, this raise an error:

`sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Could not evaluate current criteria in Python: "Cannot evaluate BinaryExpression with operator <function concat_op at 0x7f5047a1cbf8>". Specify 'fetch' or False for the synchronize_session parameter.`

How can I use sqlalchemy to incrementally update row values of type TEXT or VARCHAR?

Comment: "Specify `'fetch'` or `False` for the `synchronize_session` parameter." Have a look at the docs for their meaning: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.update

Comment: @IljaEverilä  works like a charm. Thank you.